# Manually installing python dependencies doesn't work. Why?

Tags: python, centos, fabric

Whenever I install my python project using 'python setup.py install', and invoke my project on a CentOS vagrant box, it works great. The dependencies get resolved perfectly.

However, if I create an rpm using fpm for my project, install the rpm using 'rpm -i rpm-file.rpm', manually install the dependencies using 'pip install -r requirements-file-path.txt' and then invoke my project on another CentOS vagrant box, I get the following error:

```
  File "/usr/bin/<name-of-my-project>", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2655, in <module>
    working_set.require(__requires__)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 648, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 546, in resolve
    raise DistributionNotFound(req)
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: fabric==1.10.2
```

Uninstalling the dependencies using 'pip uninstall' and reinstalling them doesn't fix the problem. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just found the answer on the Fabric FAQ page: http://www.fabfile.org/faq.html/. Executing:

```
sudo pip install -U setuptools
```

Then re-installing the dependencies and project solved my problem. But welcome to other answers.

Comment: You should ALWAYS use `virtualenv` or `pyvenv` to avoid this kind of thing! You may not think about it now, but when you need up do a quick update and you realize that your old app was using an old lib that you just updated and everything broke.. well youre going to learn a good-cold-hard lesson. I speak from experience - make a virtual environment!